# Esc function does not get called when exiting fullscreen mode

Tags: angular

I have some content which I am making fullscreen.

What I want is to fire a function on pressing Esc which exits the fullscreen. Please go through the below link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zk6udf

**Please Note:** Kindly open the execution window in a new window by clicking [image] 
in order to properly see the fullscreen mode.

In above, when I click the button it enters in fullscreen. But when I press Esc, the hidden text doesn't show up. Instead when I press Esc again, then it does that. I am using HostListener for achieving this.

How can I achieve calling a function on pressing Esc which exits the fullscreen?

Thanks.

Comment: a stackblitz is great, but the question **itself** should contain a [mcve]. This question becomes useless if (when...) the link dies. Please check [ask]

Comment: Thanks @AJT82. I will take care of it from the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead listen to [`fullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event) in your hostlistener:

```ts
@HostListener("document:fullscreenchange", ["$event"]) onKeydownHandler(
  event: KeyboardEvent
) {
  // has exited
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) { 
    this.showTextAfterEscape = true;
  }
}
```

**Your [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebq6v9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: I didn't test extended in browsers, so I don't know if you need to also listen for all different browser types and not only `fullscreenchange`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. No, as of now I need it only for Chrome web browser.

Comment: `fullscreenchange` event has full browser support [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event). Except Safari is unknown

Comment: Actually the type of the received event is 'Event', not 'KeyboardEvent'! So in this case it's not possible to get an information about pressed key.